# Select a tileset feature in CesiumJS based on a feature attribute (in order to fly to it)

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm trying to develop a feature where I fly to an entity (a building in this case) based on an attribute it has.

A bit of context:

- I have a CityGML with a few thousand buildings I'm serving through
  Ion as a tileset.
- All of the buildings in the CityGML have an
  attribute, let's call it "BuildingID". It is unique, meaning there
  are no buildings with the same value for it.
- Currently, users can
  click on the building and the camera will fly to it, in a similar
  fashion to what's found here with "Zoom to feature" selected:
  https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=3D%20Tiles%20Interactivity.html&label=3D%20Tiles

The challenge:

- I will have a list of buildings in the UI of the app. If the user
  selects a building on that list, I can retrieve the same BuildingID
  that's in the 3D model as an attribute.
- Here's the problem: I have
  no clue on how to "select" that building in order to fly to it.

If these were other data sources such a KML, I could retrieve the entity and fly to it, but with a 3D Tileset, I don't even know where to start.

I'm using Cesium 1.57, but I have no problems in updating if necessary.